# Visual Studio 2012 Architecture Tools UML Class Diagram Code Generation

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, uml, visualization, modeling

I tried generating code from the Class Diagrams using Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate Modeling Project.

First and foremost, it generates the code fine, creates a new project for me automatically and folders per package in the UML diagram.

All is good, except how do I use the generated file?

Reason I asked, if I have operations in a class, aka methods, it will generate method stubs with NotImplementatedException().  I do want to fill in the method stubs, but upon changing the uml and generating code again, my method will be wiped and replaced with NotImplementedException again.  If I select not to override, adding a new operation won't generate a new method in my class.

Are there any best practices on how we should use this code generation thing?  The way I see it now, it is pointless.

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view, once you have generated your code skeleton, you should open it under your favorite IDE (Eclipse or Visual Studio) and fulfill the body of your method and then reverse your updated code for having a updated model.

Hoping it helps,

RB